# Rails Routes Starting Slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could someone please tell me the significance of starting slashes on routes?

```
get "search" => "hello#world"
vs
get "/search" => "hello#world"
```

both works but what's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same.  Ruby on Rails is just being forgiving by allowing both formats.  You may use them interchangeably.